# Change the background color when the pi starts up

Tags: hdmi, pi-zero-w, headless, bash

I have a setup with a headless Raspberrypi Zero attached to a screen and the `pi` user is automatically signed in so a Bash prompt is shown.

The black shell background now interferes with how I want to use that screen so I would like to change the white on black background to white on black background.

Please note that I want to change the entire black screen background to be white rather than just changing the prompt.

I have not found a method to easily do this

## Mockup

Current look at the top
Desired look at the bottom

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried any software solutions yet? This one looks promising: https://github.com/JamesH65/setgamma (made by a Raspberry Pi Engineer).

Although I don't know if it would work without a windowing system (so bash prompt only), but I'm guessing it would. It seems to write to the mailbox system (which in my understanding is quite a low-level connection from `CPU` -> `VideoCore`)

Another thing that comes to mind, is to try and find a hardware solution to change the gamma of the HMDI output before sending it to your display. Or maybe even some color correcting films, something like this: https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/163141-REG/Rosco_102302102124_E_Colour_210_6_Neutral.html

I don't really know what your intended purpose is. So this might or might not be applicable.

Cheers.